# jQuery UI Autocomplete does not respect input maxlength attribute

Tags: html, jquery, autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete widget to suggest values for an input field.

This input field had a maxLength value set to 100 characters. But when I use one of the options suggested by autocomplete, I want it to truncate the selected string to 100 characters once selected, if its length is >100.
Currently, it pasted the complete selected string and disregards the maxlength = 100 constraints.
Is there a way to truncate the string post selection from autocomplete dropdown?